# Payload contains two or more files with the same destination

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I launched my application in Visual Studio 2015 and now i am getting an error on the PlayerFramework saying that it is being loaded more then once.  Is anyone having this issue?

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Microsoft.PlayerFramework.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.PlayerFramework.Xaml\2.0.0.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Microsoft.PlayerFramework.dll
C:\Dailymotion\dailymotion-windows-universal\Dailymotion.Core\bin\Debug\Microsoft.PlayerFramework.dll   Dailymotion.Windows (Dailmotion.Windows\Dailymotion.Windows)
```